# Microstrategy pdf Export Settings

Tags: google-chrome, microstrategy

we are using Microstrategy in the company , some of the user receive an error like that once they run a document  :
"An error has occured on this page
Proprety set ExportPDFSettings is not found ."

I checked Microstrategy export pdf service it was running i restarted it but nothing have changed .
ps1 : there is some user that not suffer from this issue
ps2 : the issue happen only on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

In recent MicroStrategy editions there may be multiple PDF Export services, if it is hosted on Linux, not sure for Windows, one for dossiers and other for documents. Check if both services are UP.